# How to debug dll that is called from another dll

Tags: visual-c++

I'm developing A.dll that is called from another B.dll (that actually is COM) that is called from application C.exe like COM. I' trying to setup my VC++ 2010 to debug A.dll. I set Project->configuration properties-> Debugging->Command to C.exe. Unfortunately my program doesn’t goes through breakpoints. How to make this debug system work?

Comment: Are the pdbs for A.dll loaded (Debug -> Windows -> Modules. Check if pdb for A is loaded)? Are you checking the break points after A has been loaded?

Comment: Yes it is in the list of "Debug -> Windows -> Modules". B.dll loads immediately with C.exe and After it is loaded I call A.dll functions that are market with breakpoints.

Comment: Does modules Window say that pdb loaded for A? Can you post the screenshot of the modules Window after everything is loaded?

Comment: What means pdb? This is info from module:  A.dll C:\A.dll N/A N/A Binary was not built with debug information.  50 6.03.0.452 11/12/2012 1:46 PM 052D0000-053D1000* [1008] C.exe: Native 
This A.dll alsow marked with symbol '!' in red.

Comment: There is no possibility to post picture. I have copied text line from module info. It is posted in previous message.

Comment: It seems that pdbs were not loaded for A.dll. Have you enabled creating pdbs for A.dll. in Projects A's settings: Properties > Linker > Debugging > Generate Debug Info = "Yes"

Comment: I found the problem. It was my fault - I have done one change and build was not completed successfully. That means there was no A.dll at all. By the way, what is pdb?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/121366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you build A.dll with debug information:
 Properties > Linker > Debugging > Generate Debug Info = "Yes"

[image: Enabling PDBs for unmanaged projects]

Then make copy over the dll and pdbs to the applications output folder and start debugging.
Make sure that the pdbs for the A.dll is loaded.

Go to Debug -> Windows -> Modules. Verify pdbs for A are loaded. Else right click and click "Load Symbols From" -> Symbol Path and point it to applications folder where A.dll's pdbs are present.

[image]